# Convert Azure VM from Pay-As-You-Go to Reserved

Tags: azure, reserved-instances

I will preface this by saying we are brand new to Azure.

We ran a proof-of-concept project using a VM on a Pay-As-You-Go subscription. We're now ready to proceed to production, but want to take advantage of the better pricing that Reserved instances affords.

I've submitted two support cases related to this and still don't have a complete answer. So, I'm hoping the community can help.

I would greatly appreciate a step-by-step explanation on how to convert a VM on a pay-as-you-go subscription to a reserved instance.

Answer (score 1):

Finally received call back from support. Basically, when you buy a reserved instance matching the exact size of the VM you want to convert Azure it will automatically apply that new reserved subscription to matching VMs.